How can I find out DDL for table in Trino?
I have in Trino this kind of statement:
show create table daptr_catalog.u_schema.test
It returns this row:
CREATE TABLE daptr_catalog.u_schema.test( id bigint, name varchar ) WITH ( format = 'ORC', format_version = 2, location = 's3a://user/schema/test' )
How can I use this result as part of SELECT or how can I insert it to another table?
Or is it possible to get DDL statement for each table in SELECT?
Is there any way to find out DDL other than with SHOW command, that seems to be not usable in any other SQL statement?

What are you trying to do with the results of getting the DDL statement?   You can get columns and data types for tables from information_schema using select statements. Try this and see if that would help with what you are trying to do  select * from daptr_catalog.information_schema.tables and select * from daptr_catalog.information_schema.columns

@TimMylott I would like to get location attribute and use it elsewhere. In context, this metainformation is important for data governance, so we would like to load it to export interface.
Can you suggest, how can I work with "location" information? Because till now i found out only way of displaying it by SHOW command, but that is only "display" command.

Maybe the "$path" metadata column.  It would give you the full path to the file where the data is located, but would include that location.  Try select "$path" from daptr_catalog.u_schema.test limit 1 and see if that would work for you.
